# Why doesn't "rvm install ruby-head" do anything?

Tags: 10.10, installation, ruby, rvm

I just clean installed my ubuntu 10.10, then i installed some necessary packages and then rvm, but when I write the `rvm install ruby-head` command, then it's just like y press enter on the shell, nothing happens, even a error message, what could be happening?

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is not the final solution to this, but you can see the available list of rubies in rvm with the command

> rvm list known

Then I installed the almost last version of ruby, because ruby-1.9.2-head doesn't work too, so

> rvm install ruby-1.9.2

That's a provisory solution for this problem, now the reason? I don't know